# Running JNLP stucks on Verifying Application

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

We have a Java application, which is ran with JNLP file. It usually works fine, but we have one PC that is unable to run it, because during running JNLP progress bar stucks on Verifying Application step:
[Verifying Application step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHN4T.png)
and it doesn't move forward.

We have already tried:

- waiting for at least 15 minutes,
- downloading JNLP again,
- clearing java cache,
- installing the lastest JRE,
- Java console, but it is opened later, so it is not useful,
- tried to enable logging and tracing in Java Control Panel, but logs didn't contain any errors or exceptions.

Is there any way to debug what is happening during JNLP verification? Are there any logs available?

EDIT: this is Windows machine with 1.8.0_291-b09 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We found it!
After turning on tracing and logging in Java Control Panel:
[image]

and running JNLP with verbose flag:

```
javaws -verbose file.jnlp
```

in
C:\User\user\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\log
we have found log with errors.

In this case it was:

```
security: Failing over to CRLs: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```